# Reading/Writing a structure into a binary file

Tags: c, file-io, structure

I am running a program with 3 structures and what I am doing to read/write in the binary file is the following:

```
struct Medico
{
    int Id_Doctor;
    int Estado;
    char Nombre[60];
    char Clave_Acceso[20];
    char Especialidad[40]; 
    struct Medico *next;
};

typedef struct Medico *Medicazos;
typedef struct Medico Meds;

Medicazos Nuevo;
FILE *Archivaldo;
char especialida[40], password[20];
char nombre_doc[60];
int estado_doc, id_doc;

Archivaldo=fopen("md.dat", "rb");
fclose(Archivaldo);

if((Archivaldo=fopen("md.dat", "rb"))==NULL)
{
    printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo de Medicos\n"); //couldnt open file msg
    exit(1);
}

rewind(Archivaldo);
while(!feof(Archivaldo))
{
    if(*Inicio != NULL)  //read from file and write in struct
    {
        Nuevo = (Medicazos) malloc (sizeof(Meds)); //new=pointer
        fread(&id_doc, sizeof(int), 1, Archivaldo);
        fread(nombre_doc, sizeof(char), sizeof(nombre_doc), Archivaldo);
        fread(password, sizeof(char), 20 , Archivaldo);
        fread(especialida, sizeof(char), 40, Archivaldo);
        fread(&estado_doc, sizeof(int), 1, Archivaldo);
        Nuevo->Id_Doctor=id_doc; ///copies data in structure
        strcpy(Nuevo -> Nombre , nombre_doc);
        strcpy(Nuevo -> Clave_Acceso, password);
        strcpy(Nuevo -> Especialidad, especialida);
        Nuevo-> Estado = estado_doc;
        printf("---------------------------------\n"); //display info
        printf("ID: %d\n", id_doc);
        printf("\nDoctor: ");
        puts(nombre_doc);
        printf("\nPassword: ");
        puts(password);
        printf("\nEspecialidad: ");
        puts(especialida);
        printf("\nEstado: ");
        if(estado_doc==1)
            puts("Activo\n");
        else
            puts("Inactivo\n");
        Nuevo-> next = *Inicio;
        *Inicio = Nuevo;
     }
     else 
     {
         *Inicio = (Medicazos)malloc(sizeof(Meds));
         fread(&id_doc, sizeof(int), 1, Archivaldo);
         fread(nombre_doc, sizeof(char), sizeof(nombre_doc), Archivaldo);
         fread(password, sizeof(char), 20 , Archivaldo);
         fread(especialida, sizeof(char), 40, Archivaldo);
         fread(&estado_doc, sizeof(int), 1, Archivaldo);
         (*Inicio)->Id_Doctor=id_doc;
         strcpy((*Inicio) -> Nombre , nombre_doc);
         strcpy((*Inicio) -> Clave_Acceso, password);
         strcpy((*Inicio) -> Especialidad, especialida);
         (*Inicio)-> Estado = estado_doc;
         printf("--------------------------------\n"); //display info
         printf("ID: %d\n", id_doc);
         printf("\nDoctor: ");
         puts(nombre_doc);
         printf("\nPassword: ");
         puts(password);
         printf("\nEspecialidad: ");
         puts(especialida);
         printf("\nEstado: ");
         if(estado_doc==1)
             puts("Activo\n");
         else
             puts("Inactivo\n");
         (*Inicio) -> next = NULL;
     }
 }
 fclose(Archivaldo);
```

Is there any way to do simplify this?

**EDIT**: Also, when I try to display the files someone mentioned me not to use `feof` while for reading/writing. I dont recall why. What could be used instead?

Comment: Please tag your questions in the future with the language you're using. I tagged it with C because it looks like you're only using C.

Comment: I thought I did, im so sorry; btw everytime i seem to format the code when I post the question it doesnt seem to be on format..

Comment: Why don't you serialise your structure into something like json and store it on disk as a text (rather than binary) file. It would make debugging simpler and text files are generally more manageable than binary.

Comment: I would loveeeee to do it on a txt file, but Im required to do it in binary.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm assuming your struct looks like this:

```
struct Medicazos
{
  char Nombre[60];
  char Clave_Acceso[20];
  char Especialidad[40];
  int Id_Doctor;
  int Estado;
}
```

You can read/write/copy this guy around as a single unit. There's no need to do piecemeal access until you're ready to actually use the values.

```
struct Medicazos m = {"Bob", "Password", "Feet", 123, 456};

FILE* f = fopen(...);
fwrite(&m, sizeof(struct Medicazos), 1, f);
```

And the same (but backward) for `fread`.

(By the way, your capitalized variable names are killing me.)

Comment: +1 for the clean answer and I wish I could give you another +1 for the last comment about variable names.

Comment: I assume doing that code doesn't take endianess into account?

Comment: Im so sorry, i thought I posted the structure, the structure is in the edit of the question

Comment: @GWW not any more than the original question.

Comment: Oh I'm not trying to be confrontational.  Endianess always ends up confusing me.  The problem would be writing the file in a little-endian machine and trying to read it on a big-endian I assume?

Comment: @GWW neither am I. Literally, doing 5 freads into 5 structure fields or doing 1 fread into a whole structure, endianness doesn't affect the outcome. C structs, like arrays, are always ascending byte order. Character strings are unaffected. If transferring from a big endian machine to little endian, the two ints would have to have their bytes reversed (but not switched with each other).

Comment: @Ro Schz, now that you've added your struct, I should point out that you'll have to relink your list after reading. RAM addresses obviously won't survive writing to disk and re-reading.

Comment: What about pointers in the struct? I mean what if the struct has a pointer to an array (with lenght predefined) or to another struct?

Comment: @ozanmuyes That was not the OP's question. This question/answer are about simplifying binary IO for the given struct definition. Your question is different, and you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: @RyanCalhoun I see, thanks for the reply. I thought I could get a quick answer out of OP's question (if there's any short one).

Comment: @ozanmuyes The shortest answer is that you can't apply this answer if there are pointers in the structure. Pointers store memory addresses, and will not make sense if written and then read from a file.